# Bluetooth Unsupported

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios-bluetooth

I am developing an iOS Application that uses bluetooth. I have to connect my iPhone with windows machine bluetooth than it is working fine but sometimes I am getting manager state "Unsupported". I am using iPhone XR. I know my iPhone XR is supported and I have connected many times. But why sometimes I get manager state unsupported.

*I am testing on real device*

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ manager: CBCentralManager) {
    if manager.state == .poweredOn {
    }
    else if (manager.state == .unauthorized || manager.state == .unsupported){
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have fixed this issue by just restarting my central manager if i got Unsupported issue.